# Reduce product price from php script

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to make a php script that reduces the base price of a product by 20 but it instead changes the base price with the discounted price. I can't figure out what is wrong with the code.

```
        $product_baseprice = round(1.19*($product->base_price));
        $product->base_price = $product_baseprice - 20;
        $product->update();
```

Comment: I don't understand : you have so many clean ways to change / add reductions to product prices in back-office. Why would you do it this way ?

Comment: I need to create a php script that can be run by a cron job to reduce prices by an amount at a certain time.

Comment: Why don't you create a module with a cron callable service that create a proper Cart rule reduction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "base_price" property in the Product class object.
The base price must be updated with the `$product->price` property.

Or, like suggested, you can create a `new SpecificPrice()` where you can apply a percentage-based discount on the product.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

```
        $pret = $product->base_price;
        $pret_redus = $pret - 16.81;
        $product->price = $pret_redus;
        $product->update();
```